# List OnItemCLickListner is not working in Asyntask?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am doing this part of code and trying to parse data and set on a custombase adaptr and after that i want to make the list clcikable ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StreamPage extends ListActivity {

    String UrlForStream;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.streampage);

        RestImplimentationMethods urlretriver = new RestImplimentationMethods();

        UrlForStream = urlretriver.GenerateFullUrlforStream(getIntent()
                .getStringExtra("secret"));

        ParsingForStream(UrlForStream);

        Log.d("****Stream****URL", UrlForStream);

    }

    private void ParsingForStream(String urlForStream2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new LongOperation().execute(UrlForStream);
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements OnItemClickListener {


        private static final String TAG_streamable = "streamable";
        private static final String TAG_Title = "title";
        private static final String TAG_Description = "description";
        private static final String TAG_Image = "image";
        StreamPersingClass Spc;
        JSONArray streamable = null;

        ArrayList<StreamPersingClass> searchResultss = new ArrayList<StreamPersingClass>();

        final ListView lv1 = getListView();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jparser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);

            try {
                streamable = json.getJSONArray(TAG_streamable);

                for (int i = 0; i < streamable.length(); i++) {
                    Spc = new StreamPersingClass();
                    JSONObject c = streamable.getJSONObject(i);
                    Spc.setTitle(c.getString(TAG_Title));
                    Spc.setDescription(c.getString(TAG_Description));
                    Spc.setImage(c.getString(TAG_Image));

                    searchResultss.add(Spc);

                    Log.d("****Stream***Title***", Spc.getTitle());
                    Log.d("****Stream***Description***", Spc.getDescription());
                    Log.d("****Stream**Image Title****", Spc.getImage());

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(StreamPage.this,
                    searchResultss));


            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}
```

What i have to do now ?? Any suggestion .....I have tried another code where there was no asyn task that worked well ...

Comment: what problem u are getting with current code?

Comment: I am getting no errro but i am trying to make the listview Clickable ...but its not happening ...

Answer (score 0):

This code should be in ListActivity ie,. in your case in `StreamPage` class

```
  @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

EDIT :

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class StreamPage extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

        String UrlForStream;
        TextView tv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.streampage);

            RestImplimentationMethods urlretriver = new RestImplimentationMethods();

            UrlForStream = urlretriver.GenerateFullUrlforStream(getIntent()
                    .getStringExtra("secret"));

            ParsingForStream(UrlForStream);

setOnItemClickListener(this);

            Log.d("****Stream****URL", UrlForStream);

        }

        private void ParsingForStream(String urlForStream2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new LongOperation().execute(UrlForStream);
        }

        private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {


            private static final String TAG_streamable = "streamable";
            private static final String TAG_Title = "title";
            private static final String TAG_Description = "description";
            private static final String TAG_Image = "image";
            StreamPersingClass Spc;
            JSONArray streamable = null;

            ArrayList<StreamPersingClass> searchResultss = new ArrayList<StreamPersingClass>();

            final ListView lv1 = getListView();

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jparser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);

                try {
                    streamable = json.getJSONArray(TAG_streamable);

                    for (int i = 0; i < streamable.length(); i++) {
                        Spc = new StreamPersingClass();
                        JSONObject c = streamable.getJSONObject(i);
                        Spc.setTitle(c.getString(TAG_Title));
                        Spc.setDescription(c.getString(TAG_Description));
                        Spc.setImage(c.getString(TAG_Image));

                        searchResultss.add(Spc);

                        Log.d("****Stream***Title***", Spc.getTitle());
                        Log.d("****Stream***Description***", Spc.getDescription());
                        Log.d("****Stream**Image Title****", Spc.getImage());

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(StreamPage.this,
                        searchResultss));


                lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
            }



        }
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont set adapter in asynctask just call notifydatasetchanged(). and then try your click event.